# PHP / Apache - Best way to validate HTTPS connection

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https

I would like to learn what is the **best way**, in terms of **security**, to validate that the request was made using SSL (over HTTPS).

My environment is PHP and Apache.
I can think of many ways to do it.
It is possible to check the *$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']* and *$_SERVER['HTTPS']* variables.

It is also possible to force Apache to listen only to port 443 and to disable port 80.
It is possible to use the SSLRequireSSL directive in Apache.

And I believe there are many other options.

So, how to do it the right way?

Comment: Of course you can disable port 80 and enable port 443.

Comment: I don't think there's a "best" way as such. Checking that the connection is made via HTTPS on the server side is only part of the equation. It's ultimately the user's responsibility to check that they're using HTTPS, and to expect it (a MITM attack could provide the user with a plain HTTP connection and still make an HTTPS connection to your server). HSTS is a reasonably good way to approach this problem, but it's not really about checking that the connection you get is using HTTPS (it's about telling the user's browser to do so).

Comment: You may be interested in this, by the way: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628